# Why is my element I floated and cleared in CSS not working after the other floated elements

Tags: css, css-float

I'm trying to understand why when I use the `clear` and `float` properties on a fourth `div`, it is not floating above the first element I floated. And the first three elements have floats to the left? 
Also why is the `.main` is allowing the `.aside` to float underneath the second floated element? PLEASE SOMEONE HELP. (I also took a picture of it in browser view)!

```
.main {
  background-color: #f7f4f4;
  width: 600px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-right: 140px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #705656;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  float: left;
}

.shot {
   border: 2px solid black;
   width: 400px;
   background-color: #8bed8f;
   float: left;
}

.aside {
  background-color: #f47575;
  width: 400px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  float: left;
}

.trac {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "floating above"? Do you want the .trac div to float on top of the .main div? It might help if you also add your html

Comment: so basically yes im trying to figure out how i can do tucking the .trac div underneath the first main div. I feel like i very much understand clear and float, but for some reason the 2nd and 3rd divs stack on top of each other as if the .main div is "allowed" to give the both inline space, however those rules arent applied to the .trac div

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: @CheckLife I removed your image. Do not use vulgar language. SO isn't reddit.

Comment: Could you add an visual reference of what you're trying to achieve. I still don't understand where you want which div to be positioned on your screen.